# How to pass a url value to all subsequent items in the Scrapy crawl?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am creating a CrawlSpider to scrape a product website. From page 1, I extract category urls of the form www.domain.com/color (simplified). On the category page, I follow the first link to a product detail page, parse the product detail page and crawl to the next one via a Next link. Each color category therefore has a unique crawl path.

The difficulty is that the color variable is not on the product detail page. I can extract it from the category page by parsing the link as follows:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
        l = XPathItemLoader(item=Greenhouse(), response=response)
        l.default_output_processor = Join()
        l.add_value('color', response.url.split("/")[-1])
        return l.load_item()
```

However, I want to add this color value to the items parsed from the product detail page for the products crawled starting from a particular color category page. The product urls are crawled by following Next links, so the referring category page is lost after the first link. There is something in Scrapy docs about request.meta which can pass data between parsers, but I'm not sure this applies here. Any help would be appreciated.

My rules are:

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//table[@id="ctl18_ctlFacetList_dlFacetList"]/tr[2]/td',)),),
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//table[@id="ctl18_dlProductList"]/tr[1]/td[@class="ProductListItem"][1]',)),callback='parse_item', follow=True,),
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="ctl18_ctl00_lbNext"]',)),callback='parse_item', follow=True, ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`process_request`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.Rule) argument of your rules:

```
class MySPider(CrawlSpider):
    ...
    rules = [...
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), process_request='add_color'),
    ]

    def add_color(self, request):
        meta = dict(color=request.url.split("/")[-1])
        return request.replace(meta=meta)
```

Comment: Added current spider rules above. When I add your rule, I get error: 
`NameError: name 'self' is not defined` whichever rule it is added to. The first rule returns all the category links, so each category has a different color. Not clear on how process_request works despite reading docs.

Comment: Sorry, self was a copy/paste thing in there, it should not be there, i took it out.

Comment: I added `process_request='add_color'` to my first rule. I now get the error: `rule = self._rules[response.meta['rule']]     exceptions.KeyError: 'rule'`

Comment: @DanWalker same problem

Comment: @StevenAlmeroth You can fix your response by starting from a copy of meta (`meta = deepcopy(request.meta)`) and then defining the color (`meta['color'] = request.url.split("/")[-1]`)

Comment: @Gallaecio Have you seen [Request.replace()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.replace)?

Comment: When you pass a new meta dict to `Request.replace`, you are replacing (not merging) the `meta` of the old request. The `KeyError` exception that they are experimenting is because the new `meta` you assign to the request is missing the `rule` keyword of the old request meta. I’ll propose an edit to your response so that you see it more clearly.

Comment: I do wonder it, instead or creating a copy of the request, you could just edit the meta of the request in place and return the same request.

Comment: @Gallaecio Go ahead and submit an answer, you have good input

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [Steven’s approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16071823/939364), but editing the meta of the original request:

```
class MySPider(CrawlSpider):

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), process_request='add_color')]

    def add_color(self, request):
        request.meta['color'] = request.url.split("/")[-1]
        return request
```